# The meaning of idiom: to hay with them

Tags: idioms

I find this sentence on a mobile game

> Kids, we need to talk. Never mind my childhood memories, **to hay with them.** But all of this is going to lose us money!

What's the meaning of "to hay with them" in that sentence?

Comment: 'Hay' is possibly a euphemism for 'hell', invented by the game people. Or maybe the writing was done by a non-native speaker.  It's not an English expression.

Comment: It could just be a typing error. The text in phone games is often badly written, and very often by people whose first language is not English.

Comment: I've sometimes seen "hey" as a euphemism for "hell" ("what the hey").  So perhaps this is a further distortion of that, maybe from someone who's only heard that and not seen it written down.